# Multi Org Setup using HyperLedger Composer in multiple machines

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I am working on setting up a Business Network for Multiple Organizations (two physical machines).

I did the setup of a business network using Hyperledger Composer Playground and achieved querying, rest-server implementation etc.
I have configured a multi-org (multiple organizations) setup for a single business network in a single cloud server (Reference link used: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org). But, as in real scenario, I want to configure a multi-org functionality with two separate cloud servers.

I met with an error like below.

Error: Unable to Communicate with Peers. Peers not found.

Version of Composer : latest

Version of Fabric : V1.0

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Composer latest (v0.19) then you have to use Fabric v1.1.

If you are Running on 2 servers with 2 IP addresses you need to solve the communications (IP Addressing and Routing) between you client and the servers, **and** between the containers on each server.

For the client to server you need to manage the addresses in the connection.json files for composer.

For the connectivity between the Peers and other containers the correct solution is to use Kubernetes or Docker Swarm to manage the addressing/routing.  It is possible to use the `extra_hosts` feature of docker-compose for a simple demo but you might be restricted to one peer per org because of port conflicts.

Comment: @R Thatcher: Will try these out and get back to you.